# Matrix multiply two arrays VBA returns #value! error

Tags: arrays, vba, matrix, matrix-multiplication, autoregressive-models

I am trying to multiply two arrays in vba to extract the estimates of autoregressive parameters.

I have made two arrays;

arrx :  Variant(1 to 717, 1 to 2)

arry :  Variant(1 to 717, 1 to 1)

by using:

```
Ar = wf.MMult(wf.MInverse(wf.MMult(wf.Transpose(arrx), arrx)), wf.MMult(wf.Transpose(arrx), arry))
```

the first arg of mmult works fine, however vba returns a value error when i try to multiply arrx with arry. Note the same function works fine in excel when referencing ranges.

Any reasons of why this is or how i can fix it?